# Is there any inbuilt function available two get string between two delimiter string in C/C++?

Tags: c++

Is there any inbuilt function available to get strings between two delimiter string in C++?

Input string

```
(23567)=(58765)+(67888)+(65678)
```

Expected Output

```
23567
58765
67888
65678
```

---

```
include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> tokenize(const std::string& input)
{
  std::vector<std::string> result;
  std::istringstream stream(input);
  std::string thingie; // please choose a better name, my inspiration is absent today
  while(std::getline(stream, thingie, '('))
  {
    if(std::getline(stream, thingie, ')'))
      result.push_back(thingie);
    else
      throw std::runtime_error("expected \')\' to match \'(\'.");
  }
  return result;
}

void rtc()
{
  ifstream myfile(test.txt);
  if(myfile.is_open())
  while (!myfile.eof())
{
  getline(myfile,line);
auto tokens = tokenize(line);
  for(auto&& item : tokens)
    std::cout << item << '\n';
}
Error C4430 missing type specifier int assumed note:c++ does not support default int
ErrorC2440initializing cannot convertfrom std::vector<_ty>to int
Error C2059syntac error empty declaration
Error C2143syntax error missing;before&&
Error C2059syntax error:')'
```

Comment: Try `strtok` perhaps?

Comment: You can use [regular expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex), or strip away all unwanted character (e.g. `"()=+-"` etc) and split the remaining string on space.

Comment: @n.m. `strtok` is a good example of a function whose interface is so broken it should never be used.

Comment: @JamesKanze Engineering is an art of using broken tools. OK, I've just made this up.

Comment: Looks exactly like XY problem question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem `Is there a function to return a string between two delimiters?`

Comment: While `strtok` is horrible and non-safe it is exceptionally easy to use.

Comment: In short, probably no (there isn't any). That said, this can be easily solved with a regular expression or with a loop using a small state machine and std::find_first_of. That said, please don't use strtok. That's a collection of bugs waiting to happen.

Comment: @graham.reeds It's not particularly easy to use correctly, since you have to ensure that you don't call any other functions between its first use and the last.

Comment: Is this C or C++? The question title conflicts with the question+tags.

Comment: @James Kanze: In what way? I know you can't nest calls to `strtok` as it uses a static variable internally, but what other functions can't you call?

Comment: If you can use modern C++ or external lib, you can also use a regex.

Comment: @alexbuisson don't use a regex. You'll get downvoted on StackOverflow for no reason.

Comment: @graham.reeds Almost any function, since you can't know whether it uses `strtok` or not.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::getline`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> tokenize(const std::string& input)
{
  std::vector<std::string> result;
  std::istringstream stream(input);
  std::string thingie; // please choose a better name, my inspiration is absent today
  while(std::getline(stream, thingie, '('))
  {
    if(std::getline(stream, thingie, ')'))
      result.push_back(thingie);
    else
      throw std::runtime_error("expected \')\' to match \'(\'.");
  }
  return result;
}

int main()
{
  std::string test = "(23567)=(58765)+(67888)+(65678)";
  auto tokens = tokenize(test);
  for(auto&& item : tokens)
    std::cout << item << '\n';
}
```

[Live example here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c95da0d788f80289).

---

For those not entirely convinced by the awesome robustness of this solution, I specialized this for `double` inputs between the parentheses, and used `boost::lexical_cast` to verify the input:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

std::vector<double> tokenize(const std::string& input)
{
  std::vector<double> result;
  std::istringstream stream(input);
  std::string thingie; // please choose a better name, my inspiration is absent today
  while(std::getline(stream, thingie, '('))
  {
    if(std::getline(stream, thingie, ')'))
    {
      try
      {
        result.push_back(boost::lexical_cast<double>(thingie));
      }
      catch(...)
      {
        throw std::runtime_error("This wasn't just a number, was it?");
      }
    }
    else
      throw std::runtime_error("expected \')\' to match \'(\'.");
  }
  return result;
}

int main()
{
  std::string test = "(23567)=(58765)+(67888)+(65678)";
  auto tokens = tokenize(test);
  for(auto&& item : tokens)
    std::cout << item << '\n';
  test = "(2h567)=(58765)+(67888)+(65678)";
  tokens = tokenize(test);
}
```

[Live example here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/53bc885ac502fbf2). Now go cry about how bad `strtok` really is, or how bad/unportable the general `<regex>` implementations are currently. Also, for those who doubt `boost::lexical_cast` performance-wise, [please see the results for yourself](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/performance.html).

Comment: Cannot work he said errorc2562:tokenize void function returning a value

Comment: @user3045037 you must have copy-pasted wrong. Try again. And make sure it's `std::vector<std::string> tokenize(const std::string& input)`, and not `void tokenize(const std::string& input)`.

Comment: void rtc()
{
  ifstream myfile(test.txt);
  if(myfile.is_open())
  while (!myfile.eof())
{
  getline(myfile,line);
auto tokens = tokenize(line);
  for(auto&& item : tokens)
    std::cout << item << '\n';
}
Error C4430 missing type specifier int assumed note:c++ does not support default int
ErrorC2440initializing cannot convertfrom std::vector<_ty>to int
Error C2059syntac error empty declaration
Error C2143syntax error missing;before&&
Error C2059syntax error:')'

Comment: @user3045037 I suggest you try copy pasting my integral code example (which works and compiles), and then modify that for your needs, or post your full code which is producing that error (perhaps in a new question) through either coliru or pastebin/gist/ideone/...

Answer (score 0):

`strpbrk` can be used to find the start of each token
or `strcspn` can be used to count the characters until the next token
then `strspn` can be used to find the length of each token.

```
const char tokenChars[] = "0123456789";
char token = input;  // say input is "(23567)=(58765)+(67888)+(65678)"

while( 0 != (token = strpbrk( token, tokenChars )) )   // find token
{
    size_t tokenLen = strspn( token, token_chars );           // find length of token

    // print out tokenLen characters of token here!

    token+= tokenLen;                                  // go to end of token
}
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strspn/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcspn/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strpbrk/

Comment: -1 for using C facilities operating on `char *`s and for linking to cplusplus.com.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer if you wanna use pointers:

```
char test[32] = "(23567)=(58765)+(67888)+(65678)";
char *output = NULL;
char *pos = (char *)test;
int length = 0;
while (*pos != '\0') {
    if(*pos == '(' || *pos == ')' || *pos == '+' || *pos == '=') {
        *pos = '\0';
        if (length > 0) {
            output = new char[length + 1];
            strncpy_s(output, length + 1, pos - length, length + 1);
            length = 0;
            cout << output << endl;
            delete [] output;
            output = NULL;
        }
    } else {
        length++;
    }
    pos++;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const char input[] = "(2av67q)=(ble ble)+(67888)+(qpa)";
int s = 0;

for(int i = 0; input[i]; i++)
{
    if ( input[i] == ')' )
    {
        cout << endl;
        s = 0;
    }
    else if ( input[i] == '(' )
    {
        s = 1;
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        if ( s == 1 )
        {
            cout << input[i];
        }
    }
}
```

result:

```
2av67q
ble ble
67888
qpa
```

Comment: As simple as this is... it satisfies the test! :)

Comment: This is not valid C++.

Comment: Please enlight me - what is so terribly wrong about it that it got so many downvotes? It does exactly what OP wants.

Comment: I didn't downvote but probably because you can't initialise a `char*` with a string literal (anymore).

Comment: 1. What @Simple said, 2. it doesn't return a string, 3. It's C-isms in an answer to a C++ question. And most importantly: 4: it doesn't return the string between two delimiters, as the question is asking.

Comment: @rubenvb: Thanks for englightment ;-). I learn sth new everyday ;-). Please enlight me more - #1)why(or since when) isn't assigning string literal to char* legal/valid - I really do not know? #2) OP said nothing about returning but showed exected output #3) Subject contains C and C++ #4) OP said nothing about strings that are not numbers. ;-P

Comment: String literals in C++ are of type `const char[]`, and the conversion to `char*` was deprecated in C++03(98?). It was removed in C++11 (the current standard, which you really should be coding against).

Answer (score -1):

While some of the commentators may hate it I like this:

```
for (p = std::strtok(input, "+"); p != NULL; p = std::strtok(NULL, "+"))
{
// do more stuff
}
```

This won't work off the bat - the delimiters need expanding - it demonstrates the ease of use.

Comment: It demonstrates the ease of use of how to use `strtok` in a `for()` loop.  It won't work because I didn't put any effort into adding all the delimiters.  I leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution using a regular expression:

```
std::vector<std::string> get_numbers(std::string const& s)
{
    static std::regex regex(R"(^\((\d+)\)=\((\d+)\)(?:\+\((\d+)\))+$)",
                            std::regex_constants::ECMAScript
                            | std::regex_constants::optimize);

    std::vector<std::string> results;
    std::sregex_iterator matches(s.cbegin(), s.cend(), regex);
    for (auto first = matches->cbegin(), last = matches->cend();
         last != first;
         ++first)
    {
        results.push_back(first->str());
    }

    return results;
}
```

Comment: Now we have two problems.

Comment: Three problems! We need unit tests to show in how many ways this is broken

Comment: I'm amazed this has been downvoted when the highest answer ATM accepts more input than what was asked for.

Comment: @Simple: the question literally asks for the string between two delimiters. If you need the number, you'll perform a conversion which will check for the validity of that number after the token is extracted.

Comment: Also, your code is broken according to libc++'s `<regex>`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79e6f5d1d42617b5

Comment: @rubenvb fair enough. I don't know why it's not working because [the regex itself seems fine](http://www.regexplanet.com/cookbook/ahJzfnJlZ2V4cGxhbmV0LWhyZHNyDwsSBlJlY2lwZRia588DDA/index.html).

Comment: @Simple I don't see it working. What language do you want me to click?

Comment: @rubenvb I checked it with Java and with JavaScript on [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html). I imagine the JavaScript result is correct because that's what the C++ standard is based on.

Comment: @Simple: When I click on "Javascript" on the first link you posted, I fail to see the correct output for any of the functions called on the regex object (I don't know anything about using regexes, so bear with me). Oh, and check out my update which validates the input even better, in case of numbers.